# Use syncronous functions on Svelte with Tauri Backend

Tags: asynchronous, electron, tauri

I have an app that used to work under Electron/Svelte, and we're looking to switch to Tauri for performance and EXE size, however we meet a problem.
During initialization, we read files and used to do it synchronous, and we'd like to keep it that way (fs.openSync() for instance).

However, in the fs library from Tauri there is no Sync functions, and it does not seem like there is a possibility to bypass this.

Would anyone know how to do it, or is there no option but to manage our problem async.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Rust’s builtin sync operations ([std::fs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/fs.html)) from your backend inside a Tauri command, if you really need synchronous operations, or you could use the Tauri API asynchronously.